# Must non-pointer instance variables be released in dealloc?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, sdk, dealloc

Do I have to call `release` in the `dealloc` method of a class for non-pointer variables?

e.g.

```
@interface myClass : NSObject {

    BOOL isDirty; // do i have to release this?
    NSInteger hoursSinceStart; // and this?

    NSDate *myDate; // i will release the pointer in dealloc
}

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger hoursSinceStart; // property to release?

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isDirty; // property to release?
@end
```

Comment: no, those values will stay in the stack and will be popped up when your program calls dealloc method.

Comment: @faith I doubt dealloc has any thing to do with stack variables ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1. You only need to retain and release objects. BOOLs and NSIntegers are not objects, they're primitives.
2. You generally shouldn't call `release` for any `assign` property, because you haven't retained it — and of course `assign` is the only type that makes sense for primitives like NSIntegers or BOOLs, since you can't retain them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You will all release objects that extend NSObjects (or implement NSObject protocol).
please read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html for better understanding of memory management.

Comment: Well, technically it's any object which conforms to the `NSObject` *protocol*, and by convention (not language law) that's every class out there.

Comment: It's not mentioned in the question, but don't forget to `free()` any manually `malloc()`'d memory in `-dealloc` too. Any dynamically allocated memory, really.

Comment: @Wilbur Vandrsmith C Rules, always :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to release your BOOL or NSInteger.  As it turns out, an NSInteger is just a typedef for an int (via [is it necessary to release a NSInteger in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098005/is-it-necessary-to-release-a-nsinteger-in-iphone) )